# Embed Array in Code of create_function() in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, eval, create-function

In order to pass an array in the code of `create_function()`, passing it to the parameter works,

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$func = create_function('$arr', '
            foreach($arr as $var) echo "$var<br />";
        ');

$func($array);
```

But I'd like to embed an array in the code directly like the `eval()` capability. Like this,

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
eval( 'foreach($array as $var) echo "$var<br />";');
```

However, this doesn't work.

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$func = create_function('', '
            foreach(' . $array . ' as $var) echo "$var<br />";
        ');

$func();
```

So how do I do it? Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you insist on create_function instead of [lambda functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$func = create_function('', '
  foreach(' . var_export($array, true) . ' as $var) echo "$var<br />";
');
```

You need a (valid) string representation of the array for the php parser. [var_export](http://docs.php.net/var_export) provides that.
But [Berry Langerak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12510882/4833) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

When using PHP >= 5.3, you can use an anonymous function instead of create_function. The anonymous function can "use" a variable from the outer scope.

```
<?php
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$func = function( ) use( $array ) {
    foreach( $array as $value ) {
        echo $value;
    }
};

$func( );
```

Comment: Thanks, it works beautifully on my test server. Some of the servers I'm using are below PHP v5.3 unfortunately.

Comment: @Teno I'm sorry to tell you, but in that case some of the servers you're using are using software that's not supported and should be upgraded. PHP 5.2 end of support was in December 2010. ;)

Comment: Oh really... They are free shared hosts so I cannot do anything about it. Thanks for telling me that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure:

```
$function = function($array){

    foreach($array as $var){

        // do your stuff

    }

};

$function($yourArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm posting this only for educational purposes (it's very bad practice):

```
<?php

$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$func = create_function('', '
            global $array;
            foreach($array as $var) echo "$var<br />";
        ');

$func();
```

Why is it so awfull?

- global variables
- ugly way to create a function

If your version of PHP is at least 5.3 then use lambda function. See @Berry Langerak answer

Comment: I'm not a big fan of global variables either. Thank for your answer though.

Comment: why the downvotes? it does the job and i explained the drawbacks.